# Eclipse C++: class, namespace, enumeration not found

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

Greetings and thank you in advance!

I'm working in macOS X 10.12; Eclipse Neon 4.6, Compiling using macOS X GCC. I am receiving the following error:

```
../matrix.h:82:1: error: 'Matx' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
`Matx::~matx(){`
`^`
`../matrix.h:27:7: note: 'Matx' declared here`
```

The error is confusing due to the following `matrix.h` file:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_
#define MATRIX_H_
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class Matx {
    int ROWS, COLS ;
    int colix[COLS], rowix[ROWS] ;
    T ** array ;

    Matx(int, int) ;
    ~Matx() ;
    void rowSwap() ;
    void size( void ) ;
    void swapRows(int i1, int i2) { std::swap(this->array[i1], this->array[i2]); }
    void printMat( void ) ;


};// end class matrix

template <class T>
Matx::~Matx(){
    delete this->array ;
}// end ~matx()
```

Note there are a few more functions in the file, but the error is consistent across all of them.  I have tried defining the functions with scope resolution and without, i.e. `Matx::~m` but to no avail.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the definition of the function like this:

```
template <class T>
Matx<T>::~Matx(){
    delete this->array ;
}// end ~matx()
```

Comment: Thank you!  <T> after specifying the class...  Forgetful me.

Answer (score 0):

This Part is wrong.

```
int ROWS, COLS ;
int colix[COLS], rowix[ROWS] ;
```

your're defining arrays of size COLS and ROWS. But these are non-const member variables. You need compile time expressions. For example:

```
static constexpr int ROWS = 4;
static constexpr int COLS = 4;
```

Comment: Thank you- it turns out I didn't want/need colix[COLS], rowix[ROWS] ;